# ASP.NET MVC does not recognize styles in BeginForm

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when I add the line `@using(Html.BeginForm())` it turns out that adding that for my login screen no longer recognizes the added styles. How could I add them correctly? I just need to add that type of style in that View but it doesn't recognize the styles when I add that line of code

[image]

```
@model ContugasApp.Models.Login
    
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Login";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Bootstrap Simple Login Form</title>
    
        <style>
            .login-form {
                width: 340px;
                margin: 50px auto;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
    
                .login-form form {
                    margin-bottom: 15px;
                    background: #f7f7f7;
                    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                    padding: 30px;
                }
    
                .login-form h2 {
                    margin: 0 0 15px;
                }
    
            .form-control, .btn {
                min-height: 38px;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
    
            .btn {
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
            <div class="login-form">
                <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
                    <img src="~/Imagenes/contugas_logo.png" width="280" />
                    <h2 class="text-center">Bienvenido</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USUARIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USUARIO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CLAVE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "password" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CLAVE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        }
</body>
</html>
    
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `@using (Html.BeginForm())`, this will generate a `<form>` HTML element. And this leads your HTML page contains a nested `<form>` element which is not allowed.

Reference: [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379610/8017690)

---

Your Login form should be:

```
<div class="login-form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post
        , new { @action = "/examples/actions/confirmation.php" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    

        <!-- Form fields -->
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From below line I am assuming you have `Layout` page in which you already have `head` tag. As per W3C standards, you **can not** have two `HEAD` tags. On page load, `head` tag from layout are getting loaded NOT the `head` tag from login form hence your styles are not loaded.

```
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

In login page keep only what is required for login form. See below code for example

> ```
>  @model ContugasApp.Models.Login
>
>  @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Login";
>     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
>   }
>  
>     <style>
>         .login-form {
>             width: 340px;
>             margin: 50px auto;
>             font-size: 15px;
>         }
>
>             .login-form form {
>                 margin-bottom: 15px;
>                 background: #f7f7f7;
>                 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
>                 padding: 30px;
>             }
>
>             .login-form h2 {
>                 margin: 0 0 15px;
>             }
>
>         .form-control, .btn {
>             min-height: 38px;
>             border-radius: 2px;
>         }
>
>         .btn {
>             font-size: 15px;
>             font-weight: bold;
>         }
>     </style>
>
>     @using (Html.BeginForm())
>     {
>         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>
>         <div class="login-form">
>             <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
>                 <img src="~/Imagenes/contugas_logo.png" width="280" />
>                 <h2 class="text-center">Bienvenido</h2>
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USUARIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
>                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USUARIO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CLAVE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "password" } })
>                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CLAVE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
>                 </div>
>             </form>
>         </div>
>     } 
>  @section Scripts {
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") } // If possible keep this in layout page
> ```